# How can I mock this method in my child controller to test it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have this angular controller that has a method

```
$scope.handleChange = function (index) {
    //Logic
    $scope.$parent.doSomething();
};
```

I can't seem to find ways to test the `handleChange()` method OR the controller object with jasmine, as both tests throw this error:
`TypeError: $scope.$parent.doSomething is not a function`

I've done this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $injector, $q, $rootScope) {
var qReference = $q;
var rootScopeReference = $rootScope;
var $scope = rootScopeReference.$new();

var controllerReference = $controller('MyController', {
        $scope: $scope
    });
}));

it('Test Case-1: Mycontroller is defined', function () {
    expect(controllerReference).toBeDefined();
});
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the scope in a variable in your test class, mock the method doSomething using a spy:

```
var myScope = $rootScope.$new();

spyOn(myScope.$parent, 'doSomething');
```

Then pass it to your controller:

```
var controllerReference = $controller('MyController', {
    $scope: myScope 
});
```

And on your assertion block you do something like this:

```
expect(myScope.$parent.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Hope that helps.